# $F^{(n)} (p)$ do you first differentiate and afterward apply the Laplace?

Tags: notation, laplace-transform

If you have a Laplace transform:  $F^{(n)} (p)$, do you first differentiate and afterwards apply the Laplace?
$F(p)$ meaning $L[f(t)](p)$

Answer (score 1):

$F^{(n)}$ means the $n$th derivative **of** the Laplace transform. So, it is the result of

1. Finding the Laplace transform, and then
2. Taking derivative $n$ times

That said, a certain [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform offers another way to find this derivative.